# App crash on use of PeoplePicker, but not in same view

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, abpeoplepickerview

***Update 2, I hope this helps someone, there is a solutions at the following link: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/5498630?start=0&tstart=0 , evidently this is an iOS bug and this work around works.  I can create the new sharedPicker, but I cannot get anything from it or dismiss it, I'm not sure how to format beyond what is supplied at the link***
Any help on that is very welcome.

So my question now is how to take the following code and actually create the code for peoplePickerNavigationControllerDidCancel: and peoplePickerNavigationController:shouldContinueAfterSelectingPerson:
Thanks. I've left most of my original  post in case someone has a similar vague issue.

```
// Convoluted workaround for the iPhone 4S crash
+ (ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *)sharedPeoplePicker {
    static ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *_sharedPicker = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        _sharedPicker = [[ABPeoplePickerNavigationController alloc] init];
    });
    return _sharedPicker;
}
// then later on, use 
[YourController sharedPeoplePicker].delegate = self;
// etc.
```

My current code:

```
- (BOOL)peoplePickerNavigationController:
(ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *)peoplePicker
      shouldContinueAfterSelectingPerson:(ABRecordRef)person
                                property:(ABPropertyID)property
                              identifier:(ABMultiValueIdentifier)identifier
{
    [self displayPerson:person];
    [self.navigationController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    return NO;

}
- (void)peoplePickerNavigationControllerDidCancel:
(ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *)peoplePicker
{

    //[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    [self.navigationController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
- (IBAction)pick1:(id)sender
{
    ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *picker1 =[[ABPeoplePickerNavigationController alloc] init];
    picker1.peoplePickerDelegate = self;

    [self presentViewController:picker1 animated:YES completion:nil];

    x=1;
}
```

***Update 1, this app crashes on iPhone 4/4s, but runs in the simulator and iPhone5 if that means anything. I'm thinking its just they have enough power to get past whatever leak I have created***

I have an iOS app with a view controller where the user can chose contacts for the app using `ABPeoplePickerNavigationController` or enter numbers manually.  If numbers are entered manually there are no issues.  If the user opens and:

1. Picks a new contact from the address book
2. Updates a contact from the address book to use in the app
3. Opens and cancels the address book (all without saving the action)

Then I cannot navigate to one particular view in my app without a crash.  I am at a loss why I cannot go to this one view controller, or why it causes the crash.

I am using 5 different pickers, one for each contact I want to add and potentially save. I save as `NSUserDefaults`, but like I said, the crash persists even if the picker selection is never saved.  I can navigate to all view in the app from a sidebar navigation without incident, the only thing different about the view I fail on is that it is presented from one of the main view controllers and not my sidebar.

I appreciate any help or thoughts.  This was the first app I wrote and I'm trying to update it and failing. I want to get it functional again so I can come back and refactor it.

My implementation:

```
    - (IBAction)pick1:(id)sender
{
    ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *picker1 =
    [[ABPeoplePickerNavigationController alloc] init];
    picker1.peoplePickerDelegate = self;

    [self presentViewController:picker1 animated:YES completion:nil];
    x = 1;
}
- (IBAction)pick2:(id)sender
{
    ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *picker2 =
    [[ABPeoplePickerNavigationController alloc] init];
    picker2.peoplePickerDelegate = self;

    [self presentViewController:picker2 animated:YES completion:nil];
    x=2;
}
- (IBAction)pick3:(id)sender
{
    ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *picker3 =
    [[ABPeoplePickerNavigationController alloc] init];
    picker3.peoplePickerDelegate = self;

    [self presentViewController:picker3 animated:YES completion:nil];
    x=3;
}
- (IBAction)pick4:(id)sender
{
    ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *picker4 =
    [[ABPeoplePickerNavigationController alloc] init];
    picker4.peoplePickerDelegate = self;

    [self presentViewController:picker4 animated:YES completion:nil];
    x=4;
}
- (IBAction)pick5:(id)sender
{
    ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *picker5 =
    [[ABPeoplePickerNavigationController alloc] init];
    picker5.peoplePickerDelegate = self;

    [self presentViewController:picker5 animated:YES completion:nil];
    x=5;
}
- (void)peoplePickerNavigationControllerDidCancel:
(ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *)peoplePicker
{
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}


- (BOOL)peoplePickerNavigationController:
(ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *)peoplePicker
      shouldContinueAfterSelectingPerson:(ABRecordRef)person {

    [self displayPerson:person];
    [self.navigationController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];


    return NO;
}

- (BOOL)peoplePickerNavigationController:
(ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *)peoplePicker
      shouldContinueAfterSelectingPerson:(ABRecordRef)person
                                property:(ABPropertyID)property
                              identifier:(ABMultiValueIdentifier)identifier
{
    return NO;
}
- (void)displayPerson:(ABRecordRef)person
{
    NSString* name = (__bridge_transfer NSString*)ABRecordCopyValue(person,
                                                                    kABPersonFirstNameProperty);


    NSString* phone = nil;
    ABMultiValueRef phoneNumbers = ABRecordCopyValue(person,
                                                     kABPersonPhoneProperty);
    if (ABMultiValueGetCount(phoneNumbers) > 0) {
        phone = (__bridge_transfer NSString*)
        ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(phoneNumbers, 0);
    } else {
        phone = @"[None]";
    }
    if (x==1){
        firstName1.text = name;
        contact1.text = phone;
    }
    if (x==2){
        firstName2.text = name;
        contact2.text = phone;
    }
    if (x==3){
        firstName3.text = name;
        contact3.text = phone;
    }
    if (x==4){
        firstName4.text = name;
        contact4.text = phone;
    }
    if (x==5){
        firstName5.text = name;
        contact5.text = phone;
    }

}
```

Comment: And where exactly is it crashing ? Probably you are not retaining some variables.

Comment: If I edit this code out, my app runs fine, it just requires manual entering of phone numbers.  As far as debugging I get an F, I can't understand anything Xcode says and all I get now is an lldb. I will go back through and verify my saving, but what kills me is I use one method to save no matter the entry method, and even if I just bring up the picker view and don't save, I can cancel it, my app will still crash when I go the this one specific view.

Comment: More information: I have a series of view controllers embedded in a navigation controller.  From the home screen I can navigate anywhere without issue. If I open the PeoplePicker on my contacts view controller, then go back home to initiate contact, my app crashes. This happens regardless of action taken with the PeoplePicker.  When I reopen the app, it will function fine on all screens until I open PeoplePicker again? Is this some view release issue?

Comment: Just add exception breakpoint and see where it crashes. Paste a code / function class where it crashed

Comment: int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool {
        return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
    }
}

Comment: libobjc.A.dylib`objc_msgSend:

Comment: Ok, this one looks more useful.
013-11-23 13:52:31.606 EmergencyAlert[4063:60b] -[OS_xpc_connection barStyle]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x14799c30
2013-11-23 13:52:31.612 EmergencyAlert[4063:60b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[OS_xpc_connection barStyle]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x14799c30'

libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

Comment: Since `barStyle` is a property of a UITabBar rather than whatever was at that memory address when you got the error, something is likely being released too soon.  To see what it is, I suggest editing your build scheme to use zombies.

Comment: I did have a TabBar in the app and removed it, I will look for references of that. I used zombies and didn't find anything useful, however I might just not have looked through thoroughly enough.  Heres to getting something successful

Comment: Updated original post, found fix for iOS bug, but can't implement the workaround myself, too rookie for it without an example

Comment: Has this been filed as a radar with Apple? https://bugreport.apple.com ? (Also if you do, please duplicate it at http://openradar.appspot.com)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry to answer my own question, but another work around to this that requires little change is to use CF Retain to correct the over release I was experiencing.  I retained the person and the peoplePicker and all was resolved. Thanks for everyone who tried to help me solve this.

```
- (void)peoplePickerNavigationControllerDidCancel:
(ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *)peoplePicker
{

    [self.navigationController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
   CFRetain((__bridge CFTypeRef)(peoplePicker));
}
- (BOOL)peoplePickerNavigationController:
(ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *)peoplePicker
      shouldContinueAfterSelectingPerson:(ABRecordRef)person
                                property:(ABPropertyID)property
                              identifier:(ABMultiValueIdentifier)identifier
{
    [self displayPerson:person];
    [self.navigationController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    CFRetain(person);
    CFRetain((__bridge CFTypeRef)(peoplePicker));
    return NO;

}
```

Comment: With the caveat that it'll leak once the underlying bug is fixed, yes? The singleton workaround presumably avoids that issue.

Answer (score 1):

Thank You for the work around this issue. Your method #2 really works!!! 
I have the similar situation discussed in https://discussions.apple.com/thread/5498630?start=0&tstart=0 : MKMapView is placed by IB in storyboard, no code  except IBOutlet. I present ABPeoplePickerController then simply cancel it by dismiss and leave this view by navigation. Then return back and get memory issue: called method barStyle of zombie UINavigationBar at address of dismissed ABPeoplePickerController. This situation happened only on iOS 7 (iPad 3rd ten and iPhone 4S) but code works fine on iOS 6 (iPhone 3GS) and only with combination with MKMapView. I test with WebView instead of MapView and all works fine. I think it is real bug in iOS 7.
Kind regards
Alexey

Answer (score 0):

Well, there is also a bit more simple solution to this. The actual problem is in using `ABPeoplePickerNavigationController` as a singleton object, setting its delegate to a view controller and then dismissing the view controller. So, in my case the solution that worked is this one:

```
- (void)peoplePickerNavigationControllerDidCancel:
(ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *)peoplePicker
{
    peoplePicker.peoplePickerDelegate = nil; // clear delegate prior to dismissing self
    [self.navigationController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}

- (BOOL)peoplePickerNavigationController:
(ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *)peoplePicker
      shouldContinueAfterSelectingPerson:(ABRecordRef)person
                                property:(ABPropertyID)property
                              identifier:(ABMultiValueIdentifier)identifier
{
    [self displayPerson:person];
    peoplePicker.peoplePickerDelegate = nil; // clear delegate prior to dismissing self
    [self.navigationController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    return NO;
}
```