# Crash when loading MKMapView

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, uinavigationcontroller, mkmapview

I am having a peculiar crash when loading `MKMapView`. The pattern of occurrence is when I open ABPeoplePickerNavigationController in one view, which in turn triggers the `UINavigationController` delegate method

And after saving/without saving I move to another view--its working fine. Next view--its working fine. But when I enter the view with `MKMapView`, it crashes.

No other views are having any problem. Only the view which loads `MKMapView` crashes with the following log

```
*** -[UINavigationBar barStyle]: message sent to deallocated instance
```

I have commented the part in the code which loads the mapview and then it works fine. So it seems that my navigation bar is deallocated somewhere, when the mapview loads. But what I cant understand is that, no other view in the app has any problem, only the one with mapview crashes. I have tried different patterns of testing and made sure that none of the other views are having any problems.

The app doesn't crash in simulator. It crashes only on device. Why is this issue only in the view which loads mapview and in no other views.

I tried profiling to analyze my problem. Here is what I found, but its not much helpful.

[image: Profile --> Zombies]

Comment: `UIBarButtonItem *buttonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"contacts",@"Contacts") style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(cancel:)];` This is the reason behind crash. Have you used `UIBarButtonItemStylePlain` ?

Comment: Can you set an Exception breakpoint to narrow it down to the exact line of code that triggers the crash?

Comment: @JaiGovindani It doesn't seem to crash in code.

Comment: You mean it doesn't crash when you're running in a simulator? How about running it on a device but connected to Xcode?

Comment: Exactly. It doesn't crash in simulator. Only in device it cranes.

Comment: The Exception breakpoint should still work when debugging on device. Or do you mean that it doesn't crash when debugging on a device using Xcode?

Comment: @JaiGovindani It crashes. But not in any written line of code.

Comment: Just to be clear, you've set an Exception breakpoint? This should stop execution in the line of code just before the exception is raised. So even with an Exception breakpoint set (and turned on) it crashes without stopping on any particular line of code?

Comment: Yes. I have put an exception break point and still I cant find out the line of code where the app crashes.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43537/discussion-between-xavi-valero-and-jai-govindani)

Comment: You need to show us the code where you invoke the map view, as that is where the crash occurs. Is it in one of those bar button methods or elsewhere? Can you also show how _this_ navController is invoked and dismissed, as the crash is caused when you send a message to a dealloc'd controller. My guess is that you are invoking or dismissing something incorrectly (either the nav controller or the map view), but without more code I could not be sure. Can you post the project up somewhere?

Comment: In didLoad I just make a MKMapView object and loads it. And it doesn't crash on a particular line of code. But if I remove/comment the line of code where I load the mapview, it doesn't crash.

I also tried removing/commenting the code and load mapview from storyboard and its the same result. The crash is exactly the same.

Currently I am not in a position to post the code here, but will do that ASAP.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20146979/app-crash-on-use-of-peoplepicker-but-not-in-same-view.  The question (not the accepted answer) contains a link to this workaround: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/5498630?start=15&tstart=0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have had the same problem.

It's a leak issue on the ABPeoplePickerNavigationController. You have to ensure it won't be deallocated.

I'm declaring it as a strong property to ensure it won't be deallocated and it works fine :)

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20146979/app-crash-on-use-of-peoplepicker-but-not-in-same-view.  That question (not the accepted answer) contains a link to this other workaround: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/5498630?start=15&tstart=0

Answer (score 0):

Well, there is also a bit more simple solution to this. The actual problem is in using ABPeoplePickerNavigationController as a singleton object, setting its delegate to a view controller and then dismissing the view controller. So, in my case the solution that worked is this one:

- (void)peoplePickerNavigationControllerDidCancel:
  (ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *)peoplePicker
  {
  peoplePicker.peoplePickerDelegate = nil; // clear delegate prior to dismissing self
  [self.navigationController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
  }
- (BOOL)peoplePickerNavigationController:
  (ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *)peoplePicker
    shouldContinueAfterSelectingPerson:(ABRecordRef)person
                              property:(ABPropertyID)property
                            identifier:(ABMultiValueIdentifier)identifier
  {
  [self displayPerson:person];
  peoplePicker.peoplePickerDelegate = nil; // clear delegate prior to dismissing self
  [self.navigationController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
  return NO;
  }

Comment: Then wouldn't it crash all the time, and not at particular instances.